# How to clear caches automatically while refresh a page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am building a website using php + jquery.

In a jquery ajax page, I have to clear caches every time by ctrl +F5, otherwise, the buttons of this page can not be clicked.

My thought is refresh this page mandatorily by "window.location.reload(true);" , but I could not clear the caches at the same time！

Is there any Jquery or something can clear the caches automatically after clicking the buttons instead of ctrl +F5?

my codes are below:

```
...
$("[id = One_Click_Accept]").click(function(){

...

    $.ajax({
        url: WebsitePath + '/accreditation_check/' + CurAccreditationId,

        data: {
            accreditation_id: CurAccreditationId,
            IsAccredited: 1,
            CheckerName:$('#CheckerName').val(),
            CheckTime: Math.round(new Date().getTime()/1000).toString(), //it need a 10 digit timestamp to save to the db.
            TheCountry : TheCountry,
            TheSchool: TheSchool,
            TheDegree: TheDegree,
            TheMajor: TheMajor,
            YearOfGraduation: YearOfGraduation
        },
             type: "POST",
             dataType: 'json',
             cache: false,
        success: function (Result) {

            if (Result.Status == 1) {

                alert('认证成功');

            } else {
                alert('认证失败');

                $("#One_Click_Accept").val('再次认证');
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('认证失败');
            $("#One_Click_Accept").val('再次认证');

        }
    });
}
//window.location.reload(true);
});
```

Comment: **I have to clear caches every time by ctrl +F5, otherwise, the buttons of this page can not be click.**, wait i'm not clear what happen.. how come not refreshing the page disable a button..?

Comment: since you have caches why you dont disable this from server side ?

Comment: If there is a disabled button that should be clickable, why not enable it? Why did you disable it in the first place?

Comment: You could use `cache.delete();` more info https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache/delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you guys!
I resolved it by using "setTimeout(function()" to delay the load time.
Not only that, I had to use a different selector, It looks like "$(document).on('click',"[id = One_Click_Accept]",function(e) ".